# $\frac{d(f(x,y))}{dx}$ when y is a function of x

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

If I have $z=f(x,y)$ and I know $f$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}$ how can I calculate $\frac{dz}{dx}$?

For example:
$z = x+y, \frac{dy}{dx}=e^{x}$

Is there a rule that I can apply to any arbitrary function $f$?

Comment: Notice that $df(x,y) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy$

Comment: Given the confusion of the author, it’s probably best to avoid such notation.

Comment: The chain rule for multivariate functions generalizes very nicely. $f(g(x))’= f’(g(x))g’(x)$. Here, one can take $g: x\mapsto (x,h(x))$ and $f: (x,y)\mapsto x+y$

Comment: Thank you. @openspace I found the explanation here and it was helpful. https://www.ma.imperial.ac.uk/~jdg/AECHAIN.PDF